# unexpected delete behavior google spreadsheetApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a very simple script to (onEdit) check a cell for a value in Google Sheets and copy/paste the line on which the edit was made to another sheet in the same spreadsheet. Here's my code so far:

```
function onEdit(e) {



var ss = e.source //get sheet from edit event 
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();

if (s.getName() == 'currKarma') 
    {
  var test = checkCellValue(e);  //check cell value
      if (test == true) {
        var rowRng = e.range.getRow();
        var copyVals = s.getRange("A" + rowRng + ":" + "G" + rowRng) //get the range for the row that contained the edited cell 
        var newSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];  
        newSheet.insertRowBefore(1);
        var pasteRange = newSheet.getRange("A1:F1"); 
        copyVals.copyTo(pasteRange); //copy range to second sheet
        s.deleteRow(rowRng) //delete row that was copied          
                         };

    }
function checkCellValue(e) {
var chkData = e.value;
return chkData == "no";    
}

}
```

Everything seems to be working... Except that the script is copying/deleting two rows instead of one. Not sure what's going on, and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, after a little digging, I'm getting closer to an answer. I had conditional formatting set for the onEdit trigger cell, and it appears that my function to check the cell's value was getting called twice, once when the value was entered, then again when the formatting was applied. Any insight on how to avoid this is still much appreciated.

Comment: What does you conditional formatting look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check for the `changeType` of the `event` that triggered `onEdit`. [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). There's are enums for the `changeType` that can filter out your call for it not to be executed twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This got me thinking about the types of triggers, simple and installable, and I realized that I had stacked triggers. I added an installable trigger, then named the function onEdit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work-around using PropertiesService created to solve a similar problem I had with "double execution on edit event", if you don't want to do the installable trigger where you can work with changeType.

```
function onEdit(e){

var delete_count = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("delete_count"); 

if (delete_count == null)  {
   e.source.deleteRow(e.range.getRow())//or call some other function here
   var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); 
   properties.setProperty("delete_count", 1)   
  }
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty("delete_count")  
}
```

Blocks the second onEdit(e) -> .deleteRow() instance.